# pygame.error: Invalid bits per pixel (range is {8...32})

Tags: python, pygame

I come here with a specific question I have yet to find an answer for, related to the pygame library. My issue in peculiar is relative to triggering the fullscreen, which was as follows in this piece of code:

```
class SHMUpyGame(object):
def __init__(self):

    pygame.init()  # Start up pygame

    if fullscreen is False:
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((windowx, windowy), pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
    else:
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((windowx, windowy), pygame.DOUBLEBUF, pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    self.flags = pygame.Surface.get_flags(self.screen)
    self.caption = pygame.display.set_caption("SHMUpy - Main")
    self.background = pygame.Surface(self.screen.get_size()).convert()
    self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('mono', 12)
```

Which returns me the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/SHMUPY_ENGINE/main/engineOOP.py", line 61, in <module>
    SHMUpyGame().go()
  File "C:/SHMUPY_ENGINE/main/engineOOP.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((windowx, windowy), pygame.DOUBLEBUF, pygame.FULLSCREEN)
  pygame.error: Invalid bits per pixel (range is {8...32})
```

I imagine that this has something to do with pygame.FULLSCREEN being there, but I couldn't figure it out.

Could someone help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're putting `pygame.FULLSCREEN` in where the `depth` parameter to `set_mode` goes (see [the docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode), that's the third argument).

What you wanted to do instead was combine the two flags, and pass that combination as the second argument (`flags`). You combine flags using the bitwise OR operator (the pipe `|`):

```
pygame.display.set_mode((windowx, windowy), pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

Always remember to check and re-check the docs first for these kinds of questions. If you look at the documentation for this function (linked above), right before it lays out the available flags, there's this piece of information that would have helped you out:

> The flags argument controls which type of display you want. There are several to choose from, and you can even combine multiple types using the bitwise or operator, (the pipe “|” character).

Comment: Oh, huh, haven't thought of using OR before. Many thanks to you!